# function without statement c++

Tags: c++, hevc

I'm tracing hevc code. encountered a weird function without statement:

```
 Void encode( Bool bEos,
               TComPicYuv* pcPicYuvOrg,
               TComPicYuv* pcPicYuvTrueOrg, const InputColourSpaceConversion snrCSC, // used for SNR calculations. Picture in original colour space.
               TComList<TComPicYuv*>& rcListPicYuvRecOut,
               std::list<AccessUnit>& accessUnitsOut, Int& iNumEncoded );
```

and somewhere call it :

```
m_cTEncTop.encode( bEos, flush ? 0 : pcPicYuvOrg, flush ? 0 : &cPicYuvTrueOrg, snrCSC, m_cListPicYuvRec, outputAccessUnits, iNumEncoded, m_isTopFieldFirst );
```

I can't trace forward because of this function.It doesn't do anything

Comment: Read a book on C++ about function declarations.

Comment: "*Without statement*" ?

Comment: `Void` is not a common C++ keyword. Either it is defined (or possibly `typedef`ed) somewhere, or you copied it wrong. (Okay – it is in `TypeDef.h`, as `typedef       void                Void;`. Why??)

Comment: Do you mean "without _definition_"? If yes, there _must_ be a definition _somewhere_, otherwise the code won't compile.

Comment: For clarity, please add what you are looking at. Is it https://github.com/dhananjay92/HEVC-Encoder-Parallel?

Comment: @GillBates: Try reading it as "without statements", or "without any statements".  Note that Chinese (and I think other East Asian languages) don't *have* plurals, so native speakers of these languages find getting plurals right *very* hard.  (They also don't have articles, so they find getting those right hard too.)

Comment: The declaration is in the header file (.h or .hpp) and the defintion is in the cpp file (https://github.com/dhananjay92/HEVC-Encoder-Parallel/blob/273067eacf187320c9450dd0bdc289a4f41a48c1/source/Lib/TLibEncoder/TEncTop.cpp)

Comment: @doctoriove thanks , I found the function "statement". Sorry for wasting your time. I use Eclipse too read the code. it's  always unstable. I tapped Ctrl+left click on that function, It couldn't trace to where it defined. now I know where the function is. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking at is a *declaration* (function prototype). Somewhere, there will be a *definition* (function, with the same name and signature, with the statements).

If there is no definition, there will be a linker error (because there is code attempting to call it, as you've pointed out), unless the calling code has been optimised away (which I'd regard as unlikely).

I would say ... keep searching, and check each search hit carefully.

**Update:** It is usual to have pairs of files, eg `NameOfClass.h` and `NameOfClass.cpp`. The declaration (without statements) in the .h (header) file, the definition (with the statements) in the .cpp file.

As @Sven points out, it could also be in a library, so the situation can get a little murky. But the good C++ programmers would put the name of the library (`NameOfLibrary.so` or .a or .dll) at the top of their .h file(s).

Comment: Yeah, somewhere there will be a definition, unless this is something imported from a library.

Comment: @SvenNilsson yes, doctorlove cracked it. I'll edit my answer to clarify the usual .h and .cpp pairings.